# How can I draw a line border around a raster field in a Basemap plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm plotting some scalar fields on a map using the `contourf` function in a `Basemap` plot (e.g. see below). However, I want Basemap to draw a border around the region covered by each scalar field. This is because the fields are seamless but are at different resolutions, and I want to be able to distinguish which regions are covered by which field. Each field has simple rectilinear lat/lon boundaries, so the border would be simple (just four lat/lon segments). Is there a straightforward wary of doing this?

```py
    m8 = Basemap(projection='tmerc', lon_0=125, lat_0=26.2, width=1.5e6, 
                  height=1.4e6, resolution='i', ax = a8)

    # Coordinates for the child and parent grids respectively
    tsx, tsy = m8(lon_rho, lat_rho)
    tsx2, tsy2 = m8(lon_rho2, lat_rho2)
    m8.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,81,5.), labels=[0,1,1,0], linewidth=0.5,
                    **{'fontsize':7})
    m8.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,351.,5.), labels=[0,1,1,0], linewidth=0.5, 
                    **{'fontsize':7})

    # Parent field
    m8_2 = m8.contourf(tsx2, tsy2, sst_a2, levels=np.linspace(tmin,tmax,num=25),cmap=cmo.thermal, vmin=tmin, vmax=tmax)

    # Child field
    m8_ = m8.contourf(tsx, tsy, sst_a, levels=np.linspace(tmin,tmax,num=25),cmap=cmo.thermal, vmin=tmin, vmax=tmax)

    m8c = m8.contour(tsx, tsy, sst_a, levels=range(tmin, tmax+1), colors='k', linestyles='dashed', linewidths=0.5, alpha=0.8)
    m8c.levels = [nf(val) for val in m8c.levels]
    fmt = '%r'
    a8.clabel(m8c,m8c.levels, fmt=fmt, inline=True, fontsize=8, colors='k')
    cNorm = colors.Normalize(vmin=tmin, vmax=tmax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your scalar fields has its own set of data, `(tsx, tsy)`. From a set of such data, you can create `convexhull` polygon that can be used to represent the extents of each filled-contours on your plot.

If you can share your `reproducible` code with data, more people can help, and the answers will be more elaborated.